# AngularJS $http.get method return null error in Firefox. With IE work great

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have some problem with $http.get method in AngularJS. It's little strange because everything works great when I use IE, but when I use Firefox get method returns null exception without any info why it's not work.

My code:

```
 $scope.getData = function () {
        var surveyApiUrl = config.api.host + config.api.paths.survey;
        debugger;
        mainService.httpMethods.get(surveyApiUrl).success(function(data) {
            debugger;
            $scope.surveyData = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            debugger;
            alert(e);
        });
}
```

Some web api:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

Result with IE:
[IE result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EBrQ.png)

Result with Firefox:
[Firefox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1aH3.png)

Comment: Possibility of CORS.

Comment: I have on server side cors enable for all headers:
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] .
When I just type api url in firefox, the result is correct. Only with $http.get method doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post error in English ?

Comment: Error is null. The get method doesn't have any information about error. Method arguments are empty.

Comment: Can you post code for `mainService.httpMethods` ? Also try to change promise for method to `then` as `success` and `error` are deprecated.

Comment: It's part of code: ' httpmethods:{
            get: function (url, id) {
                if (id != null && id != '')
                    url += '/' + id;
                return $http.get(url);
            },
            post: function (url, data) {
                return $http.post(url, data);
            }
        }'

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**
Problem was with cors configuration on server side. I added only attribute to web api controller but there is required enable cors in configuration file too.

Solution which work for me:

In webapi config:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

In webapi controller (there is required Microsoft Asp.NET Cross-Origin Support package which is available in NuGet):

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class SurveyController : BaseController
```